# Develop Calendar app for iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, calendar

According to my client requirement I have assigned to develop calender app same as http://itunes.apple.com/app/momagenda/id387027303?mt=8

Please give me some idea or code from where and what I should start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an iPhone calendar sample that might help get you started:

http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=244